# How to find the highest and the lowest number stored in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print the highest and lowest integer number stored in an array. I am able to print the highest but for the lowest I am not getting the correct result.

Consider my two classes below :

```
class ArrayUtilityNew
{
    public static int findMaxMin(int a[])
    {
        int n=a.length;
        int n2=n-1;
        int minNo=0;
        int count=0;
        int maxNo=0;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]<a[j])count++;

            }
            //This gives the highest no. if the count is 0
            if(count==0)
            {
              maxNo=a[i];

            }

          //Lowest no. shall be gained here if the count is greater
          // than the no of elements in the array

           // if(count>n)
           // {
            //    minNo=a[i];
           // }

            count=0;
        }
        return maxNo;            
    }

}

class ArrayInteractionsNew
{
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        int one[]={3,20,1999,2,10,8,999};
        int answer=ArrayUtilityNew.findMaxMin(one);
        System.out.println("The highest no in the array is "+answer);   
    }        
}
```

Is the logic behind the **second if** not correct or is there some other mistake?

How can it be corrected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution is way too complex... A better and more efficient solution would be this:

```
int n=a.length;
int minNo=a[0];
int maxNo=a[0];

for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
{
     if(a[i] > maxNo) {
         maxNo = a[i];
     } else if(a[i] < minNo) {
         minNo = a[i];
     }
}

// do whatever you want with maxNo and minNo
```

Also an even more efficient (in the code size way) way would be to use lists or streams because you can do one-liners with it.

EDIT: less ambiguous code and explanations about efficiency

Comment: Why would using lists be more efficient? Array accesses are quite fast and there's no need tor dynamic length here.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What about returning values? How would you return min and max value through the function that returns int?

Comment: @hexafraction Because it's one-liners. But yeah, arrays need a few more lines but are faster.

Comment: @hexafraction You should clarify what kind of efficiency  do you need. If it's a performance issue or something else?

Comment: @Fouss Just remove the word "efficient" and word "lists" because you don't know what are you talking.

Comment: @Fouss Your code somewhat matches the approach i've used . This helped me . Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You could return an `int[]` of `min` and `max`. Start with an array of two elements, loop over the array<sup>**1**</sup> like

```
public static int[] findMinMax(int[] a) {
    int[] result = { Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE };
    for (int i : a) {
        result[0] = Math.min(result[0], i);
        result[1] = Math.max(result[1], i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The result will be an array with the first element being the minimum value<sup>**2**</sup>. Then to test it,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 3, 20, 1999, 2, 10, 8, 999 };
    int[] minMax = findMinMax(arr);
    System.out.printf("%s: min=%d, max=%d%n", 
            Arrays.toString(arr), minMax[0], minMax[1]);
}
```

And I get (as I would expect)

```
[3, 20, 1999, 2, 10, 8, 999]: min=2, max=1999
```

<sup>**1**<sub>Here, with a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).</sub></sup>

<sup>**2**<sub>And the second element being the maximum.</sub></sup>

Comment: Why findMinMax() is public? Do you want it to call from other classes. Static methods should be called with the class perefix. Why not to use Data Object with two properties instead of array?

Comment: @RomanC "Static methods should be called with the class perefix" Not if you statically import it, or it is in the same class' `main` method.

Comment: @AndyTurner Huh? Static imports are available *only* in Java 7 and higher, other users should use prefix even if  it's the same class.

Comment: @RomanC [Java 5+](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import), actually.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is n^2.  To find min and max it only needs to be order n.

In other words you only need to look linear.

Do a loop that looks through the list once.  Keep track of min and max as you go. Initially set min = maxvalue and max=minvalue.  When you find a value smaller than min, it becomes the new min.

Here is an example in pseudo code.

```
min = max_int
max = min_int
for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
    if array[i] < min 
        min = array[i]
    if array[i] > max
        max = array[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach, if it even works, is needlessly complicated.

- Create two variables: `minNo` and `maxNo`.
- Set `minNo` = `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `maxNo` = `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
- Loop through the array.  If the element is `>= maxNo`, assign its value to `maxNo`.  Also (not instead -- i.e., not `else if`!), if the element is `<= minNo`, then assign its value to `minNo`.
- After the loop, `minNo` and `maxNo` will be correctly assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Streaming API in java8, this is a two-liner:

```
int[] array = new int[] {5,7,2,9,10,24,3,23};

int min = IntStream.of(array).min().getAsInt();
int max = IntStream.of(array).max().getAsInt();
```

Or as a more efficient 3-liner:

```
Arrays.parallelSort(array);
int min = array[0];
int max = array[array.length -1];
```

Comment: What about to extend IntStream with minmax()?

Comment: The OP is just learning.  Isn't this a bit over his head?

Comment: The second solution is even less efficient. Time complexity solution 1: 2n -> o(n). Time complexity solution 2: o(n*logn) [quicksort].

Comment: @netskink Yes ,  I have just started and haven't used the IntStream till now but would definitely use it. It really shortens the code .

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void minMax(int []arr){
     int min = arr[0];
     int max = arr[0];
     for(int i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
         min = Math.min(min,arr[i]);
         max = Math.max(max,arr[i]);
     }
//do whatever you want with the max and min
}
```

Comment: Instead posting only the code please add some explanation what the code does it will be helpful.